# Regular expression for wind Direction condition(s)

Tags: javascript, regex

I wish to write a regular expression to check wind direction condition(s). I want input from the user something like this:

```
BETWEEN (45 AND 90) OR (270 AND 320)
```

`BETWEEN`, `AND` and `OR` are of course keyword there can be multiple conditions within brackets `()` separated by `OR`

**For example:**

```
BETWEEN (45 AND 90)

BETWEEN (45 AND 90) OR (270 AND 320)

BETWEEN (15 AND 40) OR (170 AND 200) OR (270 AND 320)

BETWEEN (45 AND 90) OR (270 AND 320) OR (220 AND 240) OR (270 AND 320)
```

Numeric values should be between 0 and 360. I want to give the user option to input multiple conditions.

Comment: do you only want to check whether the string is of that format, or do you want to access the number values as well?

Comment: Numeric values as well please because direction cannot be more than 360 Degree

Comment: -1..question is unclear and incomplete

Comment: @Ali What do you want..a `regex` to validate or to access its values..`edit your question`...

Comment: @Anirudha I want a javascript regex to validate the input on the client side. I can do the rest on server side to access the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^BETWEEN \(([0-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]|3[0-5][0-9]|360) AND ([0-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]|3[0-5][0-9]|360)\)( OR \(([0-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]|3[0-5][0-9]|360) AND ([0-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]|3[0-5][0-9]|360)\))*$/
```

This is pretty long, but it makes sure that you only have `OR` **between** multiple directions and not at the end or the beginning. The length number-strings also make sure you only have numbers from 0 (or 000) to 360.

However, you should consider, whether splitting your string at `OR` and `AND` might be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

This will validate your line and return matches between the parenthesis.  It also ensures numbers are between 0 and 360.

```
^BETWEEN(?:\s*(\((?:[0-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]|3[0-5][0-9]|360)\s+(?:AND)\s+(?:[0-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]|3[0-5][0-9]|360)\))\s*(?:(OR)(?!$))?)+$
```

SUCCESS:

```
BETWEEN (45 AND 90)
BETWEEN (45 AND 90) OR (270 AND 320)
BETWEEN (15 AND 40) OR (170 AND 200) OR (270 AND 320)
BETWEEN (45 AND 90) OR (270 AND 320) OR (220 AND 240) OR (270 AND 320)
```

FAILURE:

```
BETWEEN (361 AND 90)
BETWEEN (15 AND 40) OR (170 AND 459) OR (270 AND 320)
BETWEEN (45 AND 90) OR (270 AND 320) OR (220 AND 240) OR (270 AND 320) OR
BETWEEN (45 AND 90) OR (270 AND 320) OR (220 AND 240) OR (270 AND 320) ORR
BETWEEN (45 AND 90) OR (270 AND 320) OR (220 AND 240) OR (270 AND 320) OR
```

It also makes use of non capturing groups `(?: )` so that only the `(### AND ###)` is captured.

Comment: This, too, will also match if the there is an additional `OR` at the end. But the use of `(?: )` is pretty good. Although he doesn't actually want to access the captures.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

`/BETWEEN ( ?\(\d+ (AND) \d+\)( OR)?)+/`

Comment: ahh...i missed the `?` after OR

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to validate the data...

```
/BETWEEN (( OR )?\(\d+ AND \d+\))+/
```

**EDIT**

Making a **single** regex that would solve your complex requirement is a very bad idea cuz the next time u access the regex for some changes,it would be a mess.Instead,

Break the code into different parts...

1>Check if its in correct format
`BETWEEN (( OR)? \((\d+) AND (\d+)\))+`

2>Now Check the individual values by accessing the groups and compare them with simple `if-else` construct

Comment: Thanks for your tip.... But I think I am not going to change the regex as it is for wind direction and I hope direction will remain between 0 and 360.... what m.buettner suggested is pretty much I wanted... Thanks for you advice anyway....